# Problem to use @extend_schema over an @actoin in DRF

Tags: python, django, swagger, openapi, drf-spectacular

hi I have a @**extend_schema** of **drf_spectacular** library in my code I need to use it over my **@action** to customize the detail in *OpenAPI*, but I get errors like that

```
Internal Server Error: /api/schema/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/62EE2B18EE2AE44F/NEW/django/webserver/django-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 482, in thread_handler
    raise exc_info[1]
  File "/mnt/62EE2B18EE2AE44F/NEW/django/webserver/django-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 38, in inner
    response = await get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/62EE2B18EE2AE44F/NEW/django/webserver/django-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 233, in _get_response_async
    response = await wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/mnt/62EE2B18EE2AE44F/NEW/django/webserver/django-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 444, in __call__
    ret = await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 442, in wait_for
    return await fut
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 52, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/mnt/62EE2B18EE2AE44F/NEW/django/webserver/django-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 486, in thread_handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/62EE2B18EE2AE44F/NEW/django/webserver/django-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/62EE2B18EE2AE44F/NEW/django/webserver/django-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/62EE2B18EE2AE44F/NEW/django/webserver/django-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/mnt/62EE2B18EE2AE44F/NEW/django/webserver/django-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/mnt/62EE2B18EE2AE44F/NEW/django/webserver/django-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/mnt/62EE2B18EE2AE44F/NEW/django/webserver/django-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/62EE2B18EE2AE44F/NEW/django/webserver/django-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/drf_spectacular/views.py", line 69, in get
    return self._get_schema_response(request)
  File "/mnt/62EE2B18EE2AE44F/NEW/django/webserver/django-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/drf_spectacular/views.py", line 77, in _get_schema_response
    data=generator.get_schema(request=request, public=self.serve_public),
  File "/mnt/62EE2B18EE2AE44F/NEW/django/webserver/django-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/drf_spectacular/generators.py", line 262, in get_schema
    paths=self.parse(request, public),
  File "/mnt/62EE2B18EE2AE44F/NEW/django/webserver/django-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/drf_spectacular/generators.py", line 227, in parse

   assert isinstance(view.schema, AutoSchema), (
AssertionError: Incompatible AutoSchema used on View <class 'WEB_SERVER.api_v1.views.Device'>. Is DRF's DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS pointing to "drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema" or any other drf-spectacular compatible AutoSchema?
HTTP GET /api/schema/ 500 [0.10, 127.0.0.1:51558]
```

and it's my code:

```
    @extend_schema(summary="short summary")
    @action(detail=True, methods=["GET"], url_name="command")
    def command(self, request, pk) -> Union[Response, Http404]:  # Retrieve Command

        data = request.data
        status = get_object_or_404(Command_Model, device=pk)
        serializer = Serializer_Command(status)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=Status.HTTP_200_OK)

    @command.mapping.post
    def command_create(self, request, pk) -> Response:
        data = request.data.copy()
        data["device"] = pk
        command_instace = None
        try:
            command_instace = Command_Model.objects.get(device=pk)
        except:
            pass
        serializer = Serializer_Command(
            instance=command_instace, data=data, partial=True
        )
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception_validitor):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(data=serializer.data, status=Status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I try to move decorator to down of @action but doesn't work @extend_schema actually I don't receive any error but in OpenAPI its doesn't work

also when I remove ***@command.mapping.post*** from my code its work very well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed this problem by adding more ***@extend_schema*** to other ***extra endpoints***, if did not that you get an error like that I take

```
    @extend_schema(summary="short summary")
    @action(detail=True, methods=["GET"], url_name="command")
    def command(self, request, pk) -> Union[Response, Http404]:  # Retrieve Command
        data = request.data
        status = get_object_or_404(Command_Model, device=pk)
        serializer = Serializer_Command(status)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=Status.HTTP_200_OK)

    @extend_schema(summary="short summary")
    @command.mapping.post
    def command_create(self, request, pk) -> Response:
        data = request.data.copy()
        data["device"] = pk
        command_instace = None
        try:...
```